# Why supersingular isogeny graphs are expander graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, elliptic-curves, random-graphs, graph-connectivity

I'm studying isogeny graphs and in particolar isogeny graphs of supersingular elliptic curves.

In a supersingular isogeny graph $\mathcal{G}_\ell(p)$ nodes are supersingular elliptic curvers $E$ over $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$, up to isomorphism, and edges are $\ell$-isogenies between them.

When $p\neq \ell$, the graph is connected.
Moreover, it is a $\ell+1$-regular graph and the number of its nodes is $\sim p/12$.

I understood all these properties, but I can't find a proof of the following statement

> *Supersingular isogeny graphs are expander graphs*

Do you have any references where the proof is carried out with all the steps?
Or is this thing trivial (but I can't understand it)?

Thank you for help.

Comment: I think i've heard that the adjacency matrix gives an action on the Hecke operator on some space of modular forms (maybe the cusp forms of some weight), the you can use some results from this theory to bound the eigenvalues. I'll see if i can find a reference

Comment: Ok if you navigate to the Wikipedia page for [supersingular isogeny graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersingular_isogeny_graph), this is one of the results stated and there are a few references listed. The idea is what I stated above - the action is on the space of level $p$ cusp forms of weight $2$, then the Ramanujan-Pettersen conjecture (which has been proved in this case) is used to bound the eigenvalues.

Comment: The typical reference is Pizer - Ramanujan graphs and Hecke operators 1990 (but I haven't read it).